# HTML5 charts-Customizing tooltip formatting in Jasper Studio

Tags: highcharts, formatting, jasper-reports, tooltip

I am using HTML5 bar charts for one of the report. I have a question on tooltip formatting option we have for charts. I need to display amount values for each of the series (coutry in my case) in the graph and the amount should be formatted based on each currency. So, the decimal format will change for each value.
     Under Tooltip -> Formatting, I see an option called Value decimals which allow us to configure the decimal places. But, this is a constant value and I cannot get different decimal points for different series. I tried to use the expression in this field but it is not helping as the bar chart is present in summary band and always picks up last value. Is there any way to include custom formatting in "Point Format" option of formatting? I tried to include some HTML codes in it, but it is not working. Please do let me know if there are any other way to handle this issue.
       I tried using tooltip.Formatter function, but I don't see that formatting has been applied to the chart result. Below are the values I am using in different properties.

```
    tooltip.formatter  - "(function() {return  this.series.name + '<b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, this.point.exponent)+ '</b>' ; } )"

 tooltip.pointFormat - <span style="color:{point.color}">●</span> {series.name}: <b> {point.y} </b><br/>
```

(point.exponent is a bucket property I defined for each series)

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

This is working now. We need to enable function execution for highcharts in Jasper studio preferences and once we do that, the above solution is working fine.